# Android PAHO MQTT messageArrived callback not triggering

Tags: android, mqtt

I have been trying to incorporate MQTT into one of my Android applications.  I originally had it working within an activity and have since tried to move it to a service to run in the background.  Im able to connect and send messages from the service but Im not able to receive messages.  My service implements MqttCallback and overrides the messageReceived() function but it never seems to get called.  Can someone help me understand why the callback is not firing?

```
package com.example.test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClientPersistence;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MqttService extends Service implements MqttCallback{

    final static String MY_ACTION = "MqttService";
    String username;

    //MQTT Variables
    MqttClient mySubClient;
    MqttConnectOptions connOpt;

    String BROKER_URL;
    String PUB_TOPIC;
    String SUB_TOPIC;
    String PUB_CLIENT_ID;
    String SUB_CLIENT_ID;
    Boolean MqttConnState;
    Boolean IsRunning; 



    static final String TOPIC_BASE = MyProperties.TOPIC_BASE;
    static final String PI_BROKER_URL = MyProperties.PI_BROKER_URL;    //no encryption
    static final String PI_SSL_BROKER_URL = MyProperties.PI_SSL_BROKER_URL;    //ssl enabled




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        Log.i("log_mqtt_service", "Service onStartCommand entered");

        //Get session id from previous activity
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            username = extras.getString("SESSION_ID");
        }

        //set mqtt vars
        BROKER_URL = PI_BROKER_URL;
        PUB_CLIENT_ID = "My-Pub-" + username;
        SUB_CLIENT_ID = "My-Sub-" + username;
        SUB_TOPIC = TOPIC_BASE + username;
        PUB_TOPIC = TOPIC_BASE + "test";
        IsRunning = false;


        MqttThread myThread = new MqttThread();
        myThread.start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    public class MqttThread extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(IsRunning==false)
            {
                IsRunning = true;
                connMqtt();

            }   
            while(IsRunning){
                //keep thread running
                Log.i("log_mqtt_thread_send", "thread sending mqtt message");
                sendMsg(PUB_TOPIC, "0x0001", "Message from " + PUB_CLIENT_ID);
            } 
            Log.i("log_mqtt_thread", "thread stopped");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
         super.onDestroy();
         try {
            mySubClient.disconnect();
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            Log.e ("log_mqtt_disconnect",e.toString());
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message)
            throws Exception {
        String msgStr;
        msgStr = new String(message.getPayload());

        Log.i("log_mqtt_Rx", "-------------------------------------------------");
        Log.i("log_mqtt_Rx", "| Topic: " + topic.toString());
        Log.i("log_mqtt_Rx", "| Message: " + msgStr);
        Log.i("log_mqtt_Rx", "-------------------------------------------------");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("RX_MESSAGE", msgStr);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Function to make mqtt connection and subscribe
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int connMqtt()
    {
        int result=0;
        MqttClientPersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir);

        try{
            Log.i("log_mqtt","mqtt start");
            try{
                // setup MQTT Client
                connOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
                connOpt.setCleanSession(true);
                connOpt.setKeepAliveInterval(30);
                Log.i("log_mqtt","connOpt vars setup");
            }catch(Exception e){
                result = -1;
                Log.e ("log_mqtt",e.toString());
            }

            // Connect to Broker for Subscriber connection
            try {
                mySubClient = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, SUB_CLIENT_ID, persistence);
                Log.i("log_mqtt_conn","create mqttClient");
                mySubClient.connect(connOpt);
                Log.i("log_mqtt_conn","MQTT client connected to " + BROKER_URL);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                result = -2;
                Log.i ("log_mqtt_conn","BROKER: " + BROKER_URL);
                Log.i ("log_mqtt_conn","SUB_CLIENT_ID: " + SUB_CLIENT_ID);
                Log.e ("log_mqtt_conn",e.toString());
            }


            try {
                int subQoS = 0;
                mySubClient.subscribe(SUB_TOPIC, subQoS);
                Log.i("log_mqtt_sub","mqtt client subscribed to \"" + SUB_TOPIC + "\"");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = -3;
                Log.e ("log_mqtt_sub",e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            result = -4;
            Log.e ("log_mqtt",e.toString());
        }

            return result;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Function to send  mqtt message to a topic
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sendMsg(String sendTopic, String msgid, String msg)
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String pubMsg = "{\"msgid\":\"" + msgid + "\",\"time\":\"" + timeStamp + "\", \"message\":\"" + msg + "\"}";
        int pubQoS = 0;
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(pubMsg.getBytes());
        message.setQos(pubQoS);
        message.setRetained(false);

        //Topic for publisher
        MqttTopic pubTopic = mySubClient.getTopic(sendTopic);

        // Publish the message
        Log.i("log_mqtt_send","Publishing to topic \"" + pubTopic + "\" qos " + pubQoS);
        Log.i("log_mqtt_msg", pubMsg);
        MqttDeliveryToken token = null;
        try {
            // Publish message to broker then disconnect
            token = pubTopic.publish(message);
            // Wait until the message has been delivered to the broker
            token.waitForCompletion();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("log_mqtt_error",ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Callback on your 'mySubClient.setCallBack' then only your callback methods will get called.